# Vue emit event from child to parent

Tags: vue.js

not too sure why this isn't working as all examples I read do it the same way.

**Parent.vue**

```js
<tree-select class="ml-5 tree-select"
             :nodes="all"
             :value="data"
             @tree-item:clicked="updateParent($event)"></tree-select>
```

**TreeSelect.vue**

```js
<template>
    <p class="tree-select__item">
        <span v-if="data" @click="$emit('tree-item:clicked', 0)">
```

```js
updateParent: function(event) {
   console.log(event);
},
```

My `updateParent` method is simply console logging the event. The Vue plugin for Chrome sees the event, however I don't get a console log.

---

## Edit

Changed the event from `tree-item.clicked` to `tree-item:clicked`.

---

## Edit 2

**Parent.vue**

```js
<tree-select class="ml-5 tree-select"
             :nodes="all"
             :value="data"
             @tree-item-clicked="updateParent"></tree-select>
```

**TreeSelect.vue**

```js
<template>
    <p class="tree-select__item">
        <span v-if="data" @click="$emit('tree-item-clicked', 0)">
```

Comment: Which example showed you to use hypen and dot in your event name?

Comment: @MatJ Didn't think a hypen or dot would make a difference, I just liked the naming.

Comment: @MatJ Just changed it from `tree-item.clicked` to `test` and still doesn't work.

Comment: In Vue, dot is a modifier, hypen is a caps replacement. So, If your event name is TreeItemClicked, you should bind to `tree-item-clicked` in the html, because html is case insensitive for attribute names. You cannot have neither dot nor hypen in event name.

Comment: Okay made the above change as suggested, still no luck! :/

Comment: Updated post with the changes @MatJ

Comment: @MatJ Is that true?  [This](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Event-Names) page seems to disagree.

Comment: @0x5453 I apologize, my bad. Martyn Ball, You have to use exact name, both place, and only small case.

Comment: @MatJ Which is what I am doing :/

Comment: @MartynBall Which component does this method/handler `updateParent` belong to? Just in case.

Comment: @MartynBall Your code seems to work in this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-smoke-kq3jq?file=/src/components/TreeSelect.vue). Can you update it to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @tony19 It appears to be due to my `TreeView` is a recursive component, it works in the initial component, but components it makes by calling it'self don't work.

Comment: Managed to figure it out, issue was due to it being a recursive component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue appears to be due to it being a recursive component, not sure why I can't emit from anywhere.

```
- Parent.vue // Handler here
-- TreeSelect.vue // Works here
--- TreeSelect.vue // Doesn't work
--- TreeSelect.vue // Doesn't work
---- TreeSelect.vue // Doesn't work
```

This is what I have done instead:

**Parent.vue**

```js
<tree-select class="ml-5 tree-select"
             :nodes="all"
             :value="data"
             :handle-click="updateParent"></tree-select>
```

**TreeSelect.vue**

```js
<template>
    <p class="tree-select__item">
        <span @click="handleClick(data)" v-if="data" :class="{ active: data.parent_id === value.parent_id }">
            <i :class="data.icon"></i> {{ data.label }}
        </span>
        <tree-select v-for="node in nodes"
                     :nodes="node.nodes"
                     :indent="indent+1"
                     :value="value"
                     :key="`${node.label}-key`"
                     :handle-click="handleClick"
                     :data="node">
        </tree-select>
    </p>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            data: {},
            nodes: {},
            indent: {
                default:-1
            },
            value: {},
            handleClick: Function
        }
    }
</script>
```